# SELECT same column from two different tables T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I need to grab a column called SymNumber from two different tables. Both are going to be selected using a similar criteria. Below is what I have so far and it is not working...

```
DECLARE @date datetime

SELECT @date = LastChangeDate
FROM QueueUpdates

SELECT DISTINCT u.CompanyCode, u.AgentId 
FROM SymNumberToAgentId u, AgentIdToTradingPartner a, TradingPartner t, AgentContEd c 
WHERE u.SymNumber in 
(SELECT SymNumber FROM 
(SELECT a.SymeNumber, c.SymNumber 
FROM AgentProductTraining a, AgentContEd c 
WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= @date and c.LastChangeDate >= @date) a ) and 
u.AgentId = a.AgentId and a.TradingPartnerCode = t.TradingPartnerCode and t.TradingPartnerCode = 'SE2'

GO
```

The part that is giving me headaches is the inner query listed below. I think that adjusting this portion will allow me to grab the SymNum column from both tables.

```
(SELECT SymetraNumber FROM 
(SELECT a.SymetraNumber, c.SymetraNumber 
FROM AgentProductTraining a, AgentContEd c 
WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= @date and c.LastChangeDate >= @date) a )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) or `UNION ALL` look like good options here:

```
(
    SELECT SymetraNumber 
    FROM AgentProductTraining a
    WHERE a.LastChangeDate >= @date 
    UNION
    SELECT SymetraNumber 
    FROM AgentContEd c 
    WHERE c.LastChangeDate >= @date
)
```